# Determine if this is a Martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals

I am trying to check if the process $S_t$ is a martingale, where $\mathrm dS_t = \frac{I_{S_t > 0}}{S_t} \mathrm dW_t$, $S_0 = 1$.

We know that $S_t$ is a local martingale because if we stop it at $\frac{1}{n}$ then the stopped process is an Ito Integral of a bounded process and thus is a martingale. So we also know $S_{\infty}$ exists since nonnegative local martingales are supermartingales and nonnegative supermartingales have a limit.

Now it seems intuitively clear that $S_t$ must hit zero on some positive measure set at some finite time and then stay there. Furthermore, when $S_t < M$, say, then $S_t$ is in some sense moving as fast at $\frac{1}{M}W_t$. There are many details missing here and I don't know how to fix them. Hopefully there is a simpler solution.

Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, can you post a link where I the notation $dW_t$ is explained?

Comment: The notation above means that the process $S_t$ is a stochastic integral with respect to Brownian motion $W_t$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C5%8D_calculus

Comment: By the way, I believe that it is not a martingale so one might have more luck trying to show that it is not a mg.

Comment: @ Seamus: Maybe before trying to prove that it is martingale (or not) you might be interested in the fact that this SDE has a solution in the first place ?

Comment: @TheBridge I was wondering about this very question. Seamus: If you choose $\tau_n := \inf\{t \geq 0; S_n \leq \frac{1}{n}\}$, you still have to prove $\tau_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ in order to show that it is a local martingale. As far as I can see this is not obvious, in particular if $S_t$ hits zero and stays there with probability $>0$.